# mySQL compare two different column values in trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am trying to have a trigger check if two values in a table are the same and if so insert the information into another table. My code is below.

user_id is a INT(10)
post_author_id is a VARCHAR(33) 8utf_unicode_ci

```
CASE
WHEN (new.user_id = (SELECT CAST(post_author_id AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) FROM Cvr_hooks_501_1000)) 
THEN
INSERT INTO Cvr_1_link_501_1000 (a_hook_id, a_user_id, a_post_id, a_post_author_id)

VALUES (new.hook_id, 
        new.user_id, 
        new.post_id, 
        new.post_author_id);

END CASE
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` to check if the user already existst

> ```
> CREATE tABLE Cvr_hooks_501_1000(post_author_id vaRCHAR(39))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Cvr_hooks_501_1000 VALUES ("1")
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE account(hook_id int, user_id int(11) ,post_id int, post_author_id int)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Cvr_1_link_501_1000 (a_hook_id int, a_user_id int(11) ,a_post_id int, a_post_author_id int)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER upd_check AFTER  INSERT ON account
>        FOR EACH ROW
>        BEGIN
>       IF ( EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Cvr_hooks_501_1000 WHERE post_author_id =  new.user_id)) then
>           
>           INSERT INTO Cvr_1_link_501_1000 (a_hook_id, a_user_id, a_post_id, a_post_author_id)
>
>           VALUES (new.hook_id, 
>                   new.user_id, 
>                   new.post_id, 
>                   new.post_author_id);
>
>           END IF;
>
>        END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO account VALUES(1,1,1,1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Cvr_1_link_501_1000
> ```
>
> ```
> a_hook_id | a_user_id | a_post_id | a_post_author_id
> --------: | --------: | --------: | ---------------:
>         1 |         1 |         1 |                1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1dac918b5b4c8849b71c1e013ce3dbdd)*

Comment: I tried to use the code you provided but still have the same problem. I think my issue is that I am comparing an int(11) - which is the user_id in the table - to a varchar(33) utf8_unicode_ci - which is the post_author_id. This is being done inside an INSERT AFTER trigger (on the Cvr_hooks_501_1000 table) if that makes any difference. I am pretty new to MySQL and somewhat new to the world of programming so I apologize for my lack of knowledge upfront.

Comment: @ProfessorPuff i addeed an example, see if that works with you as well.

Comment: I will take a look and see if that helps, thank you for your assistance

Comment: Well looks like the IF version you provided worked after all!!! Thank you so MUCH!